# Flex SDK : "view source" option without FlexBuilder

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I don't know if this is possible, but is there a command line tool included in the Flex SDK that allows me to do the same as the "view source" option in Flex/FlashBuilder : I'd like to generated HTML files with my source code etc but I don't have FlexBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

[ASDoc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=asdoc_1.html) (which comes with the Flex SDK) will generate HTML docs for you.  If you actually want them viewable from an online Flex application, there's some info about automating the process of adding a context-menu "view source" link [here](http://blog.wezside.co.za/2009/03/creating-viewsrc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you're not using FlexBuilder? It has a 60 day trial period and is free for students.

Also I believe Eclipse has a plug in.

Comment: The only reason I'm not using FlexBuilder is that I just wanted to know if this was possible with the Flex SDK command line tools ... I do have a FlexBuilder license ... and yes FlexBuilder does come in StandAlone and Eclipse plugin flavors
I just like playing with the command line
cheerz